# how to create an exact search using Js and Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to create an expanded search where you can find people not only using there names but some combinations... for instance i have this list of players and this peace of code work fine, but if i want to find for such features like - keeper England. this line of code doesn't work ((val.position.search(myExp) != -1) || (val.nationality.search(myExp) != -1))

```
$("#search").keyup(function() {
    var field = $("#search").val();
    var myExp = new RegExp(field, "i");
    $.getJSON("players.json", function(data) {
      var output = "<ul>";
      $.each(data, function(key, val) {
          if ((val.name.search(myExp) != -1) || (val.position.search(myExp) != -1) || ((val.position.search(myExp) != -1) || (val.nationality.search(myExp) != -1))) {
              output += "<li>";
              output += '<p class="name">' + val.name + '</p>';
              output += '<p>' + val.position + '</p>';
              output += '<p>' + val.dateOfBirth + '</p>';
              output += '<p>' + val.nationality + '</p>';
              output += '<p>' + val.contractUntil + '</p>';
              output += '<p>' + val.marketValue + '</p>';
              output += "</li>";
          }
      });
      output += "</ul>";
      $("#update").html(output);
  });
});

{  
      "id":2138,
      "name":"Thibaut Courtois",
      "position":"Keeper",
      "jerseyNumber":13,
      "dateOfBirth":"1992-05-11",
      "nationality":"Belgium",
      "contractUntil":"2019-06-30",
      "marketValue":"35,000,000 ˆ"
   },
   {  
      "id":2140,
      "name":"Jamal Blackman",
      "position":"Keeper",
      "jerseyNumber":27,
      "dateOfBirth":"1993-10-27",
      "nationality":"England",
      "contractUntil":"2019-06-30",
      "marketValue":"250,000 ˆ"
   },
```

Comment: what about `Array.filter` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do multiple search queries because you have multiple words in your query:
"england keeper" => "england" and "keeper"

So you want to filter the items by "england" and also by "keeper"..

The best would be to create a small functions, each will do a part of it:

```
// Note: this function returns the filter function
var myFilter = function(regex) {
  return function(item) {
    return regex.test(item.name)
      || regex.test(item.position)
      || regex.test(item.nationality)
  }
}

// this is a higher order function, takes the items and the full searchString as arguments
var findMatches = function(items, searchString) {
  // make a copy of the items / data
  var found = items.slice(0, item.length);

  // split the searchString, and filter the items by it
  searchString.split(' ').forEach(function(part) {
    found = found.filter(myFilter(new RegEx(part, 'i'))
  });

  return found;
}
```

Now you can use it in your code:

```
...
var output = "<ul>";
var filteredData = findMatches(data, field);
$.each(filteredData, function(key, val) {
   // filteredData should be fine, you can just render it
}
...
```